# How to write/read files from Openshift file system?

Tags: node.js, openshift

I was reading tons of post, but I don't get how to do.
I need to write a file (an ASCII one) to the server and it will read in the client side afterwards . This process is meant to be done periodically. 
I can run it locally, saving the file to my own folder.
I am using Node.js (fs module)

I know I have to put the file under the "data" folder. I don't get how to use the $OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR environment variable to do that.

I appreciate some suggestions. Thanks a lot

Ro

Answer (score 5):

You can access the data directory with environment variable process.env.OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR in node.  For example, writing to the file message.txt in data directory would be:

```
var fs = require('fs');

fs.writeFile(process.env.OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR + 'message.txt', 'Hello Node', function (err) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log('It\'s saved!');
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I am going to try it as soon as I can. Is it the same way to read the file from the client side?.

Comment: It's the same way to read a file from OpenShift's data directory by nodejs server on openshift but reading this file from client (if this is what you meant), you will need to create a RESTful API on node server side to read it and return it to client (Client cannot read this directory directly).

Comment: Thanks again for your patience, I'm totally new working with this technology.
I was thinking that perhaps I could use the REST API to store data as well, and not just to retrieve it. In that case I left behing the data folder to store permanent data.  Is it ok?

Comment: Yes, you can store the data permanently as long as you don't remove the app (nodejs server) from your openshift account.  Just a suggestion, if you plan to store quite a bit of data, you might want to add mongdb cartridge to your app and store your data there.  It's easier to insert/update/search/remove...

Comment: Thanks, that's what I will do.